# Covariance of (fractional) Brownian motions with different Hurst parameters

Tags: brownian-motion

I'd like to calculate the covariance function for fractional Brownian motions
$$
E_t \left[ dW^H(t) dW^{H'}(t) \right]
$$
but where the Hurst parameters are not equal: $H \neq H'$.

My first idea would be to look at the Riemann-Liouville representation of fractional Brownian motion (see for example [Wikipedia Fractional Brownian Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion)) and proceed from there.

Is there a better/more correct way?

**EDIT:**

According to the RLfBM representation:
$$
W^H(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma (H+ 1/2)} \int_0^t (t-s)^{H-1/2} \, dW(s)
$$
with $dW(s)$ denoting the standard Brownian motion (i.e. $H=1/2$).

So I think that
$$
E_t \left[ dW^H(t) dW^{H'}(t) \right] = \frac{t^{H + H' - 1}}{\Gamma (H+ 1/2)\Gamma (H' + 1/2)} dt
$$
In particular this gives $E_t \left[ dW^H(t) dW^{H'}(t) \right] = dt$ when $H=H' = 1/2$. Is this right?

Comment: Isn't the case H=1/2 where fbm coincides with standard wiener noise - so that would make sense where H=H'=1/2 that the expectation of the covar is dt. It's a pain to simulate but maybe brute force MC is a good way to test your more general case H<>H'.